# How to attach to database on the network

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to read mdf ldf files another PC on my network. But another PC doesnt have a SQL Server. Only have `.mdf` and `.ldf` files

I want to attach my SQL Server 2008 from network. Is it possibble?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, no different than when file is local:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [X] ON 
( FILENAME = N'\\NetworkPath\Share\X.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'\\NetworkPath\Share\X_log.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Although, I would suggest copying the files to local machine if possible.

Comment: ı use this but said "failed with the operating system error 5(access is denied.)" but ı can copy or change samething on another pc Share files. what is the problem?

Comment: @ismailtamkoç User account that is running SQL Server does not have a permission on your network folder. Note that it's not your account (which have rights) but probably SYSTEM or NETWORK SERVICE. Check in your `Control Panel \ Administrative Tools \ Services` and give appropriate rights to that user.

Comment: thank you your answer so much but how can ı do it this? ı opened services but ı dont know which one ı change? and How? I can copy or remove files this pc

Comment: Find the service named 'SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER)` or something similar (instance name is in the parenthesis). Do not change anything here, just find what is the user running services in `Log on as` column. Ask the administrator of network PC to grant access right to that user. How is that done is subject of Windows Administration, and not of this website. If you can't do that - try changing the user your SQL Server is running to someone who has rights OR set the network folder's access rights for `Everyone`.

Comment: Yes ı did it :( it didnt do

Comment: I did with server agent. I am used Mssql Express so it didnt. And now ı changed and ı did. Thank you for everything

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can copy the MDF file and LDF File and paste on machine location where SQL database files exists on which SQL Server running then you can attach it using SSMS.